# looking for a tricky one liner to get diff of awk output

Tags: linux, shell, awk, diff

Lets say i have two files like below:

```
file1

a 23
b 34
c 47

file2
a justin_beiber_sucks
b segmentation fault
c jackson
d nop
```

Now what i want is to get a diff of the first column of two file. I'm doing it now like

```
$cat file1 awk '{print $1}'> f1
$cat file2 awk '{print $1}'> f2
$diff -u f1 f2
```

But this approach feels retarded. Any tricky approach there?

Problem is i always view `pipe`s as one dimensional thing, but here its two dimensional. I mean the input to diff has to come from two different sources simultaneously.

starting point may be the awk script will read both files, do filtering and save the result in a temporary associative array, next it will invoke diff and will supply its inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

`diff -u <(awk '{print $1}' file-one) <(awk '{print $1}' file-two)`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, I wish I could edit comments.  I am going to deleted it and re-create.

Comment: Also known as Process substitution. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#PROCESS-SUB

Comment: linking this page will be more appropriate http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#PROCESS-SUB

Answer (score 1):

Chances are good that `join` will do what you want:

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

But since you don't say what you are really trying to accomplish, it's difficult to determine what options might be appropriate.